# Eclipse CDT includes 'C:' prefixed

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse (Kepler) with the CDT (8.2.1) plugin for C++ development. My problem is that when I create a new class (New->Class) the default include in the X.cpp file which should be `#include "X.h"` actually is `#include "C:X.h"`. The same thing happens when I use the 'Organize Includes' function of CDT.

I was unable to find the reason for this behaviour. 
I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with this issue.

Comment: I have the same versions of Eclipse and CDT and I cannot reproduce this (in a newly created workspace with default settings). Have you changed any settings?

Comment: I just created a new workspace and tested it. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Here is what I tested exactly: New workspace; File -> New C++ project -> Empty project; Project Name `test`, otherwise default; Rightclick project `test` -> New -> Class -> Name `testclass`, otherwise defaults; My OS is Debian.

Comment: My result for repeating your steps: `#include "C:testclass.h"`. My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too, I had created a new empty C++ project. then created my src folder and started adding classes and folders as normal. The solution i found was to set up the C++ include paths.

For those who do not know how to do that what i did was :
make sure your open project is selected in eclipse go to : "project" > "properties" > "C/C++ Build" > "Settings"

Then add include paths within "GCC C++ Compiler" > "Includes"

I am using workspace relative paths so i need this entry to exist:
"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src}"

Then beyond that add any other folders you need to access header files within.

Comment: Thanks! Although this is not exactly the solution I was hoping to find it is still very useful. The only drawback for me is that include files inside my project are now incuded the same way as default compiler includes (`#include <...>` instead of `#include "..."`). But this is not that bad.